# Does Open/Closed Principle say that we can't changed interfaces of our classes?

Tags: java, oop, solid-principles

Look at this class please:

```
public class SomeClass {

public void method1(){
    // do something
}

public void method2(){
    // do something
}

}
```

Next, imagine that 10 classes inherits this class. So, if we add parametr to method1(), for example we have to change 10 classes. This is contrary to the Open/Closed principle. So, does Open/Closed Principle say that we can't changed public interface of our classes?

Comment: You have to change more than 10 classes. You have to change every class that would be *calling* `method1()`, because none of those 0-argument calls are valid any more. I wouldn't be so worried about OCP as simple backward compatibility. Of course, if you control all of the calling code, it's fine. It really depends on context.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/310603/is-it-appropriate-to-not-follow-the-o-c-principle-if-you-have-unit-test-coverage

Comment: @JonSkeet, so if I control all calling code I can to changed public interface? If I don't control I must save old version of method and add a new version? After that I can announce old version deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - sort of...  *#8>P*

The *"Closed to changes"* bit says you should not remove the `public void method1()` signature nor change its semantics (to be delivered by all properly implementing concrete classes).

The *"Open to extension"* bit allows you to (carefully) modify the interface as long as the previous interface elements are left as is (structurally and semantically). You might try something like this:

```
public class SomeClass {

    @Deprecated
    default public void method1(){
        method1(#SENTINAL#);
    }

    public void method1(#TYPE# arg){
        if (arg == #SENTINAL#) {
            // do something old
        } else {
            // do something new
        }
    }

    public void method2(){
        // do something
    }

}
```

NOTE: This approach may not work if the argument doesn't have a useful *#SENTINAL#* value, e.g. it's an `int` and all values are valid. Often, though, there is something, like any negative, a MIN or MAX value, empty or null object, etc. When no such sentinal is available, you might create a private common method, like:

```
public class SomeClass {

    @Deprecated
    default public void method1(){
        method1(true);
    }

    public void method1(#TYPE# arg){
        method1(false, arg)
    }

    private void method1(boolean isOldWay, #TYPE# arg) {
        if(isOldWay) {
            // snore - still old clients
        } else {
            // yea! new clients are much greener!
        }
    }
}
```

PS - I say "interface" even though you are using a class. Just think of the interface as the public elements of the class, declared at the same time as the class is implemented. I generally prefer to code-to-interfaces, but that's not the OP's question, nor would it change my point (merely *where* the modifications were made - esp if using Java 8 interface-default implementations).

Comment: I disagree that "Open to extension" allows you to modify the interface — you may need to do it at times, but this is in violation of OCP then, not part of it. OCP says that if you do need to refactor & modify, that you do so in a way that's open to future extension. e.g. via something like a Visitor/Strategy pattern. See also [this article by Uncle Bob](https://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/12/TheOpenClosedPrinciple.html)

Comment: Well, it's a bit splitting hairs, but I'm thinking that as long as the client codes doesn't need to be altered it's fine (at most recompiled, but not even one brace smoothed into righteous paren *::smile::*). True, it's something of a violation of "pure" OCP, but I'm pragmatic enough to think that the spirit is maintained by ***fully*** compatible changes to the interface - isn't that why default methods actually made it into the language anyway? (Too bad we can't make them `default final`...  *::haha::*)

Comment: sure, pragmatism is always key (which too, is why it's a "principle" rather than a "rule" — it's a code smell to violate it, but that doesn't mean it should never be done).

Answer (score 0):

It is a violation of OCP. 
Close to modification means that once you've implemented the class and tested it you should not modify it anymore.
There are unpredictable cases that the business requirements suddenly changes and you have to modify your classes no matter how well you designed them.
The cleanest way to do this in your case is to add this new parameter by injecting it to the constructor of the implementing classes, or even better, inject a provider of this parameter

```
public class SomeClass{       
    IProvider _provider;

    public SomeClass(IProvider provider){
        _provider = provider
    }

    public void method1(){
        var someInput = _provider.Get();
        // do something
    }

    public void method2(){
        var someInput = _provider.Get();
        // do something
    }
}
```